# Problem finding the median when using frequency tables

Tags: average

My question concerns finding the median from a frequency table. It only occurs if you have even amounts of data. My problem is this if I had 40 bits of data in a grouped frequency table the middle values would be the 20th and 21st data points. That is fine if they appear in the same group. The median is said to be in that group. But what if they appear in different groups. The 20th in the second group and the 21st in the third group. Where does the median lie now?

Answer (score 0):

The median will be equal to the boundary value between the two groups.

Comment: Thanks that is what I had thought but wanted another opinion.